# zipped using java.util.zip getting unzip inflate error

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I zipped a folder recursively. When I try to unzip the folder using the command line I get a inflate error. I don't understand why. 
To zip the files I've pretty much done this:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/ZipFolderExample.shtml

Comment: Show the actual code you are using, not a link to something that's kind of like your code please.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file? If it's greater than 2GB (I think) older JDK's will fail. I think "older" being even earlier 1.5 versions.